# Dispatcher servlet entry in web.xml is not allowing the login view (AngularJS) to load (404)

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, authentication, spring-security

Doing SPA in AngularJS, when I remove the dispatcher servlet configuration
in `web.xml` the login view page appears, but if I place the dispatcher
servlet entry in `web.xml` login page won't load (appear) and shows HTTP 404.

I am not able to resolve this issue, should I add any extra configuration? 
Technologies used are Spring REST not MVC, Spring Security and AngularJS.

Could please somebody give the solution?

Below are the files.

`web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config> 
</web-app>
```

**test-servlet(dispatcher servlet)**.xml

```xml
<beans>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.org.simpro"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.org.simpro"></jpa:repositories> 

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    </bean>

    <bean id="HelloWorldRestController" class="com.org.simpro.controller.HelloWorldRestController">
        <property name="userService" ref="userServiceImpl"></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id= "userServiceImpl" class="com.org.simpro.service.UserServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="HR"/>
        <property name="password" value="hr"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.org.simpro.model" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">

            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                            <!-- 
                                <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
                                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>

                                //jpa hibernate properties
                                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
                                hibernate.format_sql=true
                                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
                                hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
                                hibernate.show_sql=false
                            -->
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>   
            </props>
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <import resource="security-context.xml"/> 
</beans>
```

Comment: I think this https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-login-example/ would be helpful.

Comment: used <mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/resources" /> for including the resources under the web-app folder (all the js files) but no sucess......any help ?

Comment: also don't know what  the mapping attribure value for angularjs (js ) files